# hola estoy trabajando con nodejs y npm , la momento de iniciar npm start me sale este error.. espero me puedan ayudar...saludos

Tags: nodejs, npm

> npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.13.0
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! nomada@1.0.0 start: `electron main.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the nomada@1.0.0 start script 'electron main.js'.
>
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm
>   installed.
>
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the nomada
>   package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     electron main.js
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this
>   project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs nomada
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls nomada
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Podrías enmarcarlo mas en el contexto? que teologizas tienes? Que has probado?. Te recomiendo leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Actualiza tu version de node, tienes la version 6.13, estamos en la version 8.9.* LTS o 9.6.1 actual, algunas funciones de electron requieren de versiones mas recientes

Comment: @iuninefrendor ya lo intente

apt-get install nodejs  

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

nodejs is already the newest version (6.13.0-1nodesource1).

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.

Comment: @ShadyEM actualizalo a la ultima con [n para nodejs](https://github.com/tj/n) no utilices apt-get.

Comment: @iuninefrendor me descrarga una carpeta... se supone que si muevo los docs ya debe de funcionar(?)

Comment: instala usando `npm install -g n` luego con `sudo n latest` como dice en la documentacion

Comment: @iuninefrendor lo raro es que en una maquina de manera local lo corre con node v6.12.3 al momento de subirlo al servidor nel...

Comment: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nomada@1.0.0 start: `electron main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nomada@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-28T21_32_24_953Z-debug.log


ya actualice nodejs no me salta el error de la version... ahora este :c